# R Using a list of text value output in binary when character appears more than once in a string

Tags: r, databricks, extract

Using R in Databricks.

I have the following sample list of possible text entries.

```
extract <- c("codeine", "tramadol", "fentanyl", "morphine")
```

I want check if any of these appear more than once in a string (example below) and return a binary output in a new column.

```
Example = ("codeine with fentanyl oral")
```

The output for this example would be 1.

I have tried the following with only partial success:

```
df$testvar1 <- +(str_count(df$medname, fixed(extract))> 1)
```

also tried

```
df$testvar2 <- cSplit_e(df$medname, split.col = "String", sep = " ", type = "factor", mode = "binary", fixed = TRUE, fill = 0)
```

and also

```
df$testvar3 <- str_extract_all(df$medname, paste(extract, collapse = " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine your `extract` with `|`.

```r
+(stringr::str_count(Example, paste(extract, collapse = "|"))> 1)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution works with the "Example", unfortunately not with the dataset, as only returns "0"s

Comment: I understand ... and there's nothing I can do unless you provide representative sample data and its expected output. Perhaps edit your question with the output from `head(Example,10)` or however your real data is structured?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked for my code

df$testvar <- sapply(df$medname, function(x) str_extract(x, paste(extract, collapse="|")))